# Nginx/fastcgi custom cache key

Tags: regex, caching, nginx

I'm new to nginx and have been playing around with (and reading as much as I can) about setting up fastcgi cache keys.

Ideally, I'd like the cache key value to be the entire URL (including query string) with the exception of any query string params that begin with `utm_` or `cb`.

I've learned that I can use `$host$request_uri` to set the cache key equal to the entire URL with all query strings, or `$host$uri` to do so using NO query strings. However, I can't figure out how to integrate the conditional logic.

Ideally, all of these URLs would end up with the same cache key:

```
http://example.com/?p=1&cb=8827387
http://example.com/?p=1&cb=873644
http://example.com/?p=1&utm_source=287333
```

Any assistance (especially in the regex area) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so you want to catch the entire URL by default , but if the URL includes params `utm_` or `cb` you want to ignore the entire URL ?

Comment: Hey Nader - Thanks for your reply. Almost. I want the cache key to be the entire URL (including query strings) except those query strings that start with utm_ or cb. So, in a nut shell, to cache keys in my examples above would all be the same http://example.com/?p=1. I still want it to hit the cache, just ignore the cb and utm_ query strings.

Answer (score 0):

May be this information will help you:

http://www.alexjs.eu/making-nginx-ignore-query-string-parameters/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I spent a lot of time looking at that article before initially posting the question, but I could make it work. I'm a regex novice, though, so I really felt out of my element.

Comment: The link is dead, here's the most recent one from archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20160123050205/http://www.alexjs.eu/making-nginx-ignore-query-string-parameters/